# How can I change enum values?

Tags: java, enums

I have imported org.jsmpp, which has enum class StringParameter. How can I change values of enum, in my class?

StringParameter class:

```
public enum StringParameter {

SERVICE_TYPE(StringType.C_OCTET_STRING, 0, 6, true, SMPPConstant.STAT_ESME_RINVSERTYP);

private StringType type;
private final int min;
private final int max;
private final boolean rangeMinAndMax;
private final int errCode;


StringParameter(StringType type, int min, int max, boolean rangeMinAndMax, int errCode) {
    this.type = type;
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
    this.rangeMinAndMax = rangeMinAndMax;
    this.errCode = errCode;
}


public int getMax() {
    return max;
}


public int getMin() {
    return min;
}


public boolean isRangeMinAndMax() {
    return rangeMinAndMax;
}

public StringType getType() {
    return type;
}


public int getErrCode() {
    return errCode;
}
```

I want to change SERVICE_TYPE max from 6 to 12.

Comment: What keeps you from doing it? Obviously, you have access to the source code

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I asked about is it possible to do it without changing the source code.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback. Is there anything I could add to also make the answer upvote worthy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two cases here:

- you really use `import StringParameter` somewhere in your code, and you included the corresponding class file(s) in your project setup. Then there is **nothing** you can do.
- you *copied* the source code. Then theoretically, you could just go in and make changes to that source code (assuming that the licence model allows you to do that).

Otherwise, your hands are tied. Consider enums to be **constants**, there is no changing of values at runtime.

Note: you also can't *extend* that existing enum with your own version, as well, there is inheritance for enums. If at all, you would have to create your very own enum here.

Update: of course, when you use some external library, you can theoretically do two things:

- you automate the process of downloading the JAR, unpacking it, manipulating that java enum (hopefully they provide the source code, and give you the right to do that), recompile, and repackage
- maybe contact the people owning that library, maybe there is a way to *patch* that code in ways that work for everybody

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will try to change source code. Then I should decompile classes, make my changes and compile again? I have tried it but there was issue with compiling again, because there are many dependencies form other classes. Could you advise some other way to change the inside of jar file?

Comment: @SamirAmanov As said, the very first thing is: check out the licence of that class. But yes, *manipulating* a single class out of some open-source library, that is a tough call. I will quickly update the answer, too. Beyond that: please dont go "more questions via comments ping pong". You asked a specific question, I answered it. If you know have a different question, consider to first accept an answer here, to then ask a *new* question.